# Algorithm to check if two numbers can become the same

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Hello I have to answer this question as a task. I have done the code yet I don't get full marks because apparently I am missing some conditions

Given two integers AA and BB, determine if it is possible to do the same by applying any number of the operations shown below:

- Multiply the number AA by 2.
- Multiply the BB number by 2.

If true print "felizmil", else output "tristemil"

Code

```
def ___gcd(a,b): 
    if (a == 0 or b == 0): 
        return 0
    if (a == b): 
        return a  
    if (a > b): 
        return ___gcd(a-b, b) 
    return ___gcd(a, b-a) 

def lcmOfArray(arr,n): 
    ans = arr[0] 
    for i in range(1,n): 
        ans = (arr[i]*ans)/___gcd(arr[i], ans) 
    return ans 
def checkArray(arr, num, n, m): 
    lcm = lcmOfArray(arr, n) 
    for i in range(n): 
        val = lcm/arr[i] 
        for j in range(m and val!=1): 
            while (val % num[j] == 0): 
                val = val/num[j] 
        if (val != 1): 
            return 0
    return 1
arr=list(map(int,raw_input().split()))
num = [2] 
n = len(arr) 
m = len(num) 
if 0 in arr:
    print("tristemil")
else:
    if(checkArray(arr, num, n, m)): 
        print("felizmil") 
    else: 
        print("tristemil")
```

examples-->
3 5 output: tristemil
14 7 output: felizmil

I don't know which cases/conditions I am missing i would really appreciate your help. Thanks very much :D

Comment: It is not clear what the numbers should do.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _determine if it is possible to do the same_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend A. Mercado solved this problem with the following code:

```
a, b = raw_input().split()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
if a == b:
    print("felizmil")
else:
    if a % 2 != 0 and b % 2 != 0:
        print("tristemil")
    elif a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0:
        if a > b:
            if a % b == 0:
                print("felizmil")
            else:
                print("tristemil")
        else:
            if b % a == 0:
                print("felizmil")
            else:
                print("tristemil")
    else:
        if a > b:
            if (a*2) % b == 0:
                print("felizmil")
            else:
                print("tristemil")
        else:
            if (b*2) % a == 0:
                print("felizmil")
            else:
                print("tristemil")
```

Comment: No idea what is the task. But if this piece of code works, then I think you can add 
a,b = max(a,b), min(a,b), so that you don't need to consider two cases(which one is larger) in the later lines

Answer (score 1):

Simply we can do:

```
def are_equal(a, b):
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a

    if a == 0:
        return b == 0

    while a < b:
        a *= 2

    return a == b


if are_equal(2, 4):
    print('felizmil')
else:
    print('tristemil')


if are_equal(2, 3):
    print('felizmil')
else:
    print('tristemil')


assert are_equal(0, 0) == True
assert are_equal(0, 1) == False
assert are_equal(1, 0) == False
assert are_equal(1, 2) == True
assert are_equal(2, 1) == True
assert are_equal(2, 2) == True
```